# How to add a central widget, menubar and statusbar to a "Qt Widgets Class" created by the wizard in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, qt

After adding a "Qt Widgets Class" in Visual Studio, I would like to add a central widget, a menubar and a status bar in Qt Designer, but I see no such items neither in the Widget Box nor in the context menu of the top-level QWidget added by the wizard. How I add these items?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the .ui file with a text editor, such as notepad.exe and change this:

   ```
   <widget class="QWidget" ... >
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   <widget class="QMainWindow" ... >
   ```
2. Add the "centralWidget" within the QMainWindow widget:

   ```
   <widget class="QWidget"  name="centralWidget"... >...</widget>
   ```
3. Now you can add a menubar, toolbar and statusbar from the context menu associated with the QMainWindow widget:

[image]